# In Mobile Background color showing dull when compared to desktop

Tags: html, css

Iam using background color #ff9659 in desktop its showing bright and good but when we going to mobile view the background color showing not bright and shoing dull

```css
.site-promotion {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #ff9659;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-family: 'Gotham', sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-promotion">
<a href="" target="_blank" style="color:#fff;"> Brand new to HŌMTOWN Yoga? Click here</a>
</div>
```

[image: Desktop background color]

[image: Mobile background color]

Comment: With "[...] when we going to mobile view [...]" do you mean viewing it on a mobile device or emulating mobile view on your desktop?

Comment: If you are talking about different physical devices - then you need to take into account that those can be differently _color calibrated_, and that on a mobile device you are much more likely to encounter situations of "dimmed screen" settings, to save on battery power ...